# Is there a way in pandas to filter rows in a column that are contained in a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

There is a way to check if the string in the column contains another string:

```
df["column"].str.contains("mystring")
```

But I'm looking for the opposite, the column string to be contained in another string, without doing an apply function which I guess is slower than the vectorised `.contains`:

```
df["column"].apply(lambda x: x in "mystring", axis=1)
```

Update with data:

```
mystring = "abc"
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["ab", "az"]})
df
    A
0   ab
1   az
```

I would like to show only "ab" because it is contained in mystring.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307433/6361531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one option (jpp had it) - iterate with a list comprehension:

```
df[[r in mystring for r in df.A]]

    A
0  ab
```

Or,

```
pd.DataFrame([r for r in df.A if r in mystring], columns=['A'])

    A
0  ab
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.Series([i in mystring for i in df.A])
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```